# Notepad++ regex text replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file.

```
tart*)*98'bank'ksb64bank)(tart2d&f44bank
```

I want to replace to: I want search tart*.*bank and change "bank" to "replaced"

```
tart*)*98'replaced'ksb64bank)(tart2d&f44replaced
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you purposely not replacing the second `bank`?

Comment: the 2nd bank is also in `tart*.*bank` case, buddy, it should be replaced as well. In fact if your string starts with tart*, all `bank`s should be replaced.

Comment: At least try something first..

Answer (score 1):

Find what: `(tart.*?)(bank)`

Replace with: `\1replaced`

- `()` are for grouping so you can reference groups in replace with field like `\1` for first group
- `.*` is greedy and it would match the rest of the string so `?` is for making `.*` non-greedy and matching only until first `bank` is not matched

Comment: Hi thanks but output is  

$1replaced'ksb64bank)($1replaced

I want to:

tart*)*98'replaced'ksb64bank)(tart2d&f44replaced

Comment: For me it is exactly as you want, my notepad++ is version 6.1.2 you can try with `\1replaced`